# How to remove padding from html element when pasted in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

there is a problem with inserting html into js , when inserting indents are added and I don’t understand why. Building a simple calculator

```
for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    num[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (!operator) {

            console.log(this)
            num1 += this.textContent
            ny.push(num1)
            console.log(ny)
            result.innerHTML = num1;
        } else if (operator.length > 0) {

            num2 += this.textContent
            result.innerHTML = num2;
        }


    })

}
```

[image]

Comment: .trim() it, its including the whitespace in the value because your using textContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `element.textContent` you are getting the exact content from the source HTML, including whitespace in case the HTML isn't minified.

As an alternative, you can use `element.innerText` which gives the rendered text and does not normally include extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think `this.textContent` might contain spaces and/or enters.

Instead of

```
<div>
    textContent
</div>
```

try this

```
<div>textContent</div>
```

or try:

```
this.textContent.trim().replace('\t','')
```